# Different scoping in Javascript - Lexical vs Dynamic

Tags: javascript, scope

I was going through the scoping concept and I found out that it is possible to implement both lexical and dynamic scope. Can any one help me to understand what is the major ***difference between Lexical and Dynamic scope*** in accordance of JavaScript?

Also how can we ***implement*** it in JavaScript?

Comment: JS has lexical scoping.

Answer (score -1):

In lexical scoping, the variable can be called only from within the block of the code which it is defined.  The scope of that variable is defined when the program is compiled. The variable can be accessed by its children's execution contexts. But it doesn't work backward to its parents, meaning that the variable likes cannot be accessed by its parents.

In dynamic scope, the variable declared can be called from outside the code block. In this,  the compiler will search for the variable reference in the local function first, then it searches in the function that called the local function, then it searches in the function that called that function, and so on, up the call stack. "Dynamic" refers to change, in that the call stack can be different every time a given function is called, and so the function might hit different variables depending on where it is called from.

http://wiki.c2.com/?DynamicScoping